# How to read logcat continuously and write into the internal storage file?

Tags: android, logs

Reading logcat continuously and write into the internal storage for this i tried the below code.

```
public class LogCatTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    public AtomicBoolean run = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            //create text file in SDCard
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myLogcat");
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, "logcat.txt");

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            Log.e("log cat task...","while...run.get()."+run.get());
            while (run.get()) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                //Log.e("log cat task...","while...out.");
                if (line != null) {
                    Log.e("log cat task...","while....");
                    log.append(line);
                    //publishProgress(log.toString());

                    //to write logcat in text file
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

                    // Write the string to the file
                    osw.write(log.toString());
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                }
                line = null;
                Thread.sleep(10);
                //Log.e("log cat task...","while...out.");
            }
            //Log.e("log cat task...","ouet....while....");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

once the above code runs,it read the logcat and write into storage but upto some part of the log only it reads.it is not reading the continuos.How to read the logcat continuous?

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of lines that demonstrate you have not complete understanding of what you're doing:

Here `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+file);` you make logcat output logs to the file. However here `BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));` you're trying to obtain the `InputStream` of a process that wouldn't have logs since **they are forwarded to a file**.

Here `while (run.get())` you get boolean value however you do not demonstrate where you change it.

Here:

```
//to write logcat in text file
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

// Write the string to the file
osw.write(log.toString());
osw.flush();
osw.close();
```

You open and close output stream for each line read. This is not the right thing to do from many aspects.

This line `line = null;` is not really necessary.

So, I believe once you consider all my points and fix them, you'll get your feature working. Consider also if you do really need this to do in code since `logcat -f` does exactly the same, i.e. pushing logs to a chosen file.

Comment: HI Thanks for your responce. I think logcat -f returns whenever code runs upto this logs only,after created logs how to read?